# I want to add list view new items (Except old ones) to array

Tags: java, listview, sql-server-2005

I have two list views, list one contains hotel service items that are fixed to a specific room and the other on is optional services, when i click on optional service list view item it will be added into services items. at the end all services will be viewed in list services(fixed + additional), and the price of only optional service will be saved in a db table which is optional service of the specified room

i tried on adding to delete old values and then adding optional services till the size of the added items but it doesn't work, some times it gives an error and other it prints or add only the old services and first one from the optional

`

```
for(int i=0;i<(lst1Count);i++){
lst1.getItems().remove(i);
    }   
for(int i=0;i<(lst1.getItems().size());i++){

       try {
           String queryServicePrice = "select Serviceprice from services where ServiceName ='"+lst1.getItems().get(i)+"'";
           ResultSet rsRoomService = stmt.executeQuery(q`ueryServicePrice);
           rsRoomService.next();
           Serviceprice[i] = rsRoomService.getBigDecimal(

    "Serviceprice");
               System.out.println("price"+i+" : "+Servicepric

e[i]);}
```

`